# Rails 3 - Rendering layout corrupts tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I define a function called location on wsp_controller:

```
  def location
    @title ="Edit account"
    @page_name = "edit"
  end
```

And it works fine. But when I try to render a layout like this:

```
  def location
    @title ="Edit account"
    @page_name = "edit"
    render :layout => 'signup_login' 
  end
```

RSpec tests start to fail. However, the app does what is supposed but the tests fail. 
I have javascript code in the layout that I need to run when I go to /location, if I put the javascripts on the application layout, it works (tests and app), however there's no need to put it there, so I want a new layout and render it.

How can I do that?

Edit: Here's what I have in the routes.rb

```
  match '/wsps/:id/location', :to =>'wsps#location'
```

Thanks.

Edit:

Some of the RSpec errors:

```
    Failures:
  1) WspsController GET 'index' for non-signed-in wsps should deny access to 'index'
     Failure/Error: get :index
     You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
     You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
     The error occurred while evaluating nil.errors
```

It simple doesn't pass the tests when I render the layout. But it's only in that method.

Comment: What do the failure messages say on your Rspec tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to provide a bit more info about the failures that you're getting. You mention that you have javascript that needs to run when the page is rendered? Don't forget that in your functional tests the page is rendered as html, but there isn't a real browser used, so no javascript is run. For tests that involve javascript you should look at something like Cucumber to define some acceptance tests, combined with something like Watir, or Selenium to drive a browser.

Comment: I've added come more info. Thanks